# How to Insert Data to List Using While loop

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

This is my code. I need to insert data to List form Database

```
 int gggg = 11;

 MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT mobile from student where class = "+gggg;
 MySqlDataReader rdr;
 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
     comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr["mobile"]);
     listBox1.Items.Add(rdr["mobile"].ToString());

     values.Add(["mobile"]);
 }
```

This is not working.

```
 values.Add(rdr["mobile"]);
```

above code to pass to the List via `while` loop (this code I tested with comboBox its working fine)

```
  comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr["mobile"]);
```

Comment: What isn't working? There's nothing wrong with `List.Add`. The List class is used by **all** .NET developers

Comment: How is `values` declared`?

Comment: You're trying to add `["mobile"]` in the code block you posted above.  Shouldn't it be `values.Add(rdr["mobile"]);` as you posted under it?  And unless it is a string field, it should probably be `values.Add(rdr["mobile"].ToString());` (assuming your values list is `list<string>`)

Comment: BTW Bobby Tables. *Don't* use string concatenation to create queries. Use parameterized queries

Comment: not working  no  exception not not passing data to list but working with

Comment: not working to list but working with comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr["mobile"]); this

Comment: @Shawty then you don't have any problems. LIst.Add isn't broken. As I said, *everyone* uses it and would have noticed decade**s** ago. Do you have any results to begin with? Are you connecting to the correct database? Did you try *debugging* the code? Do you have any `catch{}` statements or exception handlers that hide any errors? Are you sure the `mobile` field isn't NULL for example? That would cause an exception

Comment: now its working :)  i used values.Add(rdr["mobile"].ToString());

Comment: @Shawty I suggest you find an ADO.NET tutorial instead of trying random code. For example, you can use `DataRow.GetString(field)` to get a field's value as a string or `GetDouble()` to read it as a double etc. Don't use string concatenation in the query, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use data binding to connect controls to lists or datatables. You don't need that loop. Right now, you've tied together your UI and the data access logic which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you all <3  Now Working its perfectly  <3